# Is it possible to merge videos using AWS MediaConvert?

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, video-processing, aws-media-convert

I have two videos, A and B. I would like to combine them into a single video where they play simultaneously - with A as the background video and B as a smaller tile overlaid on top of it, similar to what you would see in a Google Meet video call. Is this possible using AWS Elemental MediaConvert?

Answer (score 1):

You can overlay still images and moving graphics over a video using *image inserter* but not full videos to my knowledge. You can control, edit and program these overlays separately within the tool such as opacity and fade in / out abilities etc.

To do this,

-Specify your input file

-For each input that you want to have a graphic overlay, do the following:

1. On the Create job page, in the Job pane on the left, under Inputs, choose the appropriate input.
   In the Image inserter section to the right of the Job pane, choose Add image, and then specify the overlay settings.
2. For Image location, specify an input file that is stored in Amazon S3 or on an HTTP(S) server.

> For Amazon S3 inputs, you can specify the URI directly or choose
> Browse to select from your Amazon S3 buckets. For HTTP(S) inputs,
> provide the URL to your input video file.

I understand this doesn’t meet your criteria as I understand. The only way I could think would be by utilising *assembly workflows* as that is more suited to working with multiple video outputs. However this is again more directed to stitching videos and but also supports  graphic overlays so you could try that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for this answer and this aws article appears to suggest that it can be done with `MediaConvert`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/assembling-multiple-inputs-and-input-clips.html